# Using Vagrant with an existing application

Tags: vagrant

Is Vagrant suitable for using locally with an existing web application, where I don't have push privileges to the app's version control repository? The app does not include a Vagrantfile itself.

The most straightforward approach I have found so far is to leave the Vagrantfile in the root folder of the application, and not to track it in version control.

My approach is slightly messy: the file always shows up as uncommitted in `git status` output,  and it's not being version controlled itself unless I was to symlink the file from an external personal repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly; but I would suggest leaving the vagrant file outside of the application's directory.

```
/code
  /myapp
  Vagrantfile
```

Then setup your Vagrantfile to map this directory like so;

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/html"
```

Then from within the guest VM, you will see

```
/var/www/html/myapp
```

Advantages based on your scenario:

- **You don't need to worry about tracking the file as it sits outside of your app.**
- You can add more apps to the code folder and run all under 1 VM (if that's what you want).

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought about having it outside of the project's folder. That makes sense!